# Proving a statement using Pigeonhole principle

Tags: pigeonhole-principle

I am trying to understand how to prove a Statement using the pigeonhole principle.

Prove the following result using the pigeon-hole principle.
In every collection of 7 integers there are at least two whose difference is divisible by 6.
any ideas? thanks in advance

Comment: Use the fact that for every $3$ consecutive integers, one will be divisible by $3$ and for every $2$ consecutive integers one will be even and divisible by $2$.

Comment: Hint:  there are exactly $6$ possible remainders on division by six.  If you have seven integers, then at least two have to have the same remainder.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the residues of the 7 numbers when divided by 6 (their classes modulo 6). There are 6 possible residues, so one must be used twice, by the pigeonhole principle. The difference of the corresponding original integers is a multiple of 6.

Answer (score 1):

There are six possible remainders modulo 6: those are $0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5$.

Since there are $7$ integers in your set, by the pigeonhole principle there will be at least two of them with the same remainder modulo 6. Their difference will then be divisible by $6$.

Answer (score 1):

By the remainder's theorem, every integer number divided by $6$ is of the form:
$$n=6q+r$$
where $0 \leq r < 6$

Since there are $6$ possible remainders, while you have $7$ numbers, at least two numbers must have the same remainder divided by $6$. Therefore, the difference of these two numbers must be divisible by $6$.